# Can we use the Common Name in TLS certificates for authorization in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

I have defined roles and permission in the Cassandra tables as defined in the documentation.
I am using client side authentication to provide access to the Cassandra DB. However, I want to use the CN (common name) from the client side TLS certificate to map it to a user/role and provide authorization. 
Is there any configuration in Cassandra that will authorize based on the CN? 
There are multiple clients and I want to ensure that only clients with proper authorization can access the DB.
I do not want the application code to pass the username but use the CN instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in the existing versions of the Apache Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware if it is planned in any future version of Cassandra.I could not find any on their site. I am asking, assuming, if you are part of their development team and is aware of such a feature

Comment: No, I'm not the part of the development team, and I don't know about plans for Cassandra. You can search on http://issues.apache.org/ for Cassandra-related JIRAs, and maybe file a new one if you don't find suitable.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10956 contains a relevant discussion. I understand this is still not possible.